# Twitter Account Activity API / Webhook URL not being removed

Tags: twitter

We have implemented a Twitter bot using Account Activity API, and it was running well.

However, we faced a problem when we decided to switch our server from Heroku to AWS.
We understand that we can create only one webhook URL. 
So to migrate our server, we have removed webhook URL connected to Heroku server, and attempted to register new webhook URL for AWS server.
But we got this error message.

> Using premium API tier, setting up a webhook URL that is already in use.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 355,
      "message": "This URL is already in use."
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems strange to us as we have removed webhook for Heroku server.
We have also checked if webhook url is being used somewhere, but the command returns empty list..

```
% curl --request GET --url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/webhooks.json --header ‘authorization: Bearer ...’ | jq
{
 “environments”: [
   {
     “environment_name”: “production”,
     “webhooks”: []
   }
 ]
}
```

It would be great if you could check whether there is a problem on Twitter side.
(Maybe, webhook url is not properly removed on your side?)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer you are looking for. But a quick and dirty way of doing it is to delete the environment and set up a new account activity environment. the only limitation is that it won't allow you to use the same environment name.